# Reducibility of $f \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)[x]$ for $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}] \geq 2$ and $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ Irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I'm struggling to make any progress on the following problem.

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ be an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ with $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]=m$, and suppose that $f \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ is irreducible.

a. Suppose that $m=2$.  Prove that either $f \in K[x]$ is still irreducible, or that $f=gh$ for $1 < \deg(g),\deg(h)$ and $\deg(g)=\deg(h)$.

b.  Suppose now that $m > 2$.  Does it follow that $f \in K[x] $ remains irreducible or factors into $m$ irreducible polynomials?

So I believe the answer to both is yes, but I'm not really sure how.  For part a, I start by supposing that $f(x) = p_1(x)p_2(x)\dots p_r(x)$ for $p_i \in K[x]$.  I want to show that the only possibility is that $r=2$, and that $\deg(p_1)=\deg(p_2)$.  I'm aware of the identification $K \cong \mathbb{Q}[x] / \langle \text{Irr}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha,x) \rangle$, and so one can think of the coefficients on each $p_i$ as being degree $1$ polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[x] / \langle \text{Irr}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha,x)\rangle$, but I have no idea what else to try.

For part b, I'm assuming that If one figures out part a properly, then part b follows by some basic inductive argument.

Any help would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: Check out for example [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/974485/11619) for possible ideas in 1) how to prove part (a) and 2) find a counterexample to part (b).

Comment: Mind you that thread is not an ideal duplicate target for this. Some others may serve better. Combined with the coincidence that I happened to answer that version I'm reluctant to vote to close.

Comment: Sorting my search results by scores lead to [this older variant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/86778/11619).

Comment: Anyway, what's the simplest non-Galois extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ you have seen? Use that to construct a counterexample to (b).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen So part b was indeed easy to figure out, however I'm still having trouble with proving part a.  I see how you did a similar problem from the link you sent, but I was told in order to solve the problem, I should use that each $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(E_K)$ (for $E$ a splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$) fixes each $p_i$, but permutes its roots, and then to consider now what elements of $\text{Gal}(E_{/\mathbb{Q}})$, but I still don't see what I'm supposed to do.  The only thing I know is that $\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ only has $1$ nontrivial automorphism.

Comment: I also know that the one nontrivial automorphism $\phi$ in $\text{Gal}(K_{/\mathbb{Q}})$ can't fix every $p_i$, and I can extend $\phi$ to all of $E$, but I again don't see how to proceed.

Comment: I have found an answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3254652/let-alpha-be-algebraic-over-mathbbq-with-mathbbq-alpha-mathbb?rq=1.  

Free bounty for anyone who wants it.